# JavaScript RegExp For Phone number validation that need to allowing hyphens and space in between the numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, angular-reactive-forms, phone-number

**App.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>First Name</label>
       <input type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber" class="form-control" >
      </div>
  </form>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
exampleForm: FormGroup;
   number_pattern=' ^[0-9_-]*$ ';

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            phoneNumber: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern(number_pattern)]
        });
    }
```

I need regex for phone with following rules, I tried regex code but its not working.

1. Field must not be empty.
2. Hyphens and space will accept in between the number not the starting and ending.
3. Must not contain anything other than numbers or blank spaces or hyphens
4. Field must not contain only blank space
5. Field must not contain only hyphens
6. Field must not contain only hyphens and blank space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about the length?

Comment: @rv7 length should be 12.

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for phone number validation.

Comment: @Mathi I mean 12 (exact), 12(min) or 12(max) ?

Comment: What about parentheses in the number?

Comment: @rv7 max 12 numbers to be allowed

Comment: @PoulBak No,  parentheses or / are not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
^\d([0-9 -]{0,10}\d)?$
```

```js
console.log(/^\d([0-9 -]{0,10}\d)?$/.test('123'));             // pass
console.log(/^\d([0-9 -]{0,10}\d)?$/.test('1-2 3'));           // pass
console.log(/^\d([0-9 -]{0,10}\d)?$/.test('1-2-3-4-5-6'));     // pass
console.log(/^\d([0-9 -]{0,10}\d)?$/.test('1-2-3-4-5-6-'));    // fail
console.log(/^\d([0-9 -]{0,10}\d)?$/.test('123456789012'));    // pass
console.log(/^\d([0-9 -]{0,10}\d)?$/.test('1234567890123'));   // fail
console.log(/^\d([0-9 -]{0,10}\d)?$/.test('- --'));            // fail
```

The three examples which fail above do so because:

- `1-2-3-4-5-6-` ends in a hyphen, not a number
- `1234567890123` has 13 digits, which is too long
- `---` contains only hyphens and spaces

Comment: This: '12-25-25-36-36-36' will not match, event though there's 12 numbers.

Comment: @PoulBak I interpreted the length requirement to apply to the entire string, not just the digits.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the ans.. its working fine as what i expected.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should do what you want:

```
^(?=.*(?:(?:\d[ -]?){1,12}))\d(?:[0-9 -]*\d)?$
```

Explanation:

`^` = from start

`(?=.*` Look ahead for zero or more of any character followed by:

`(?:` start a non capturing Group of

\d[ -]? a digit followed by an optional Space or hyphen

`{1,12}` Match 1 to 12 of those digits

`\d` match a digit

`(?:` start a new non capturing Group

`[0-9 -]*\d` a digit or a Space or a hyphen (zero or more) followed by a digit

`?` makes the Group optional

`$` match the end of the string

This will match strings with up to 12 `numbers` (+ Spaces and hyphens).

Comment: Thanks. its also working fine.